# HTML/PHP solution to enter multiple datasets as matrix like spreadsheet

Tags: php, html, mysql, dhtml

I'm looking for a good and easy HTML/PHP solution to enter multiple rows at once into a MYSQL database. 
The only solution that points into this direction is described in [Insert data using multidimensional array from multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518956/insert-data-using-multidimensional-array-from-multiple-fields) and has some destination interface that I imagined as well:
[image: example]

Now I wonder if there is not an easier and more secure solution to achieve something like this?

Comment: You could consider using Google spreadsheet and use Google Apps Script (JavaScript) to dynamicly build from MySQL and save the information when the relations are made.. also Google spreadsheet is optimzed to handle alot of rows the problem is that browsers most likely have problems to display more then 4000-5000 html inputs on one page because of high memory usage

Comment: Thanks, actually I want to integrate this into a PHP CMS in order to make it easy to edit complete tables